# Component should be returning a JSX.Element, but says it is not returning a value at all

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The component in question is this:

```
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => {
  props.map((item, index) => {
    return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
  })
};

export default NavigationItems;
```

Which is generating this error:

```
ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:1:66
TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
  > 1 | const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => {
      |                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
    2 |   props.map((item, index) => {
    3 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
    4 |   })
```

I've tried to do:

```
return props.map((item, index) => {
  <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
})
```

Which then results in:

```
ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:2:3
TS2739: Type 'void[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, key
```

Also tried:

```
return props.map((item, index) => {
  return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
})
```

Which results in:

```
ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:2:3
TS2739: Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>
```

So I'm not quite sure what is going on here.

**Any suggestions?**

---

The dataset:

```
{
  "navbar": {
    "navBrand": "My Name",
    "navItems": [
      {
        "name": "Bio",
        "href": "#bio"
      },
      {
        "name": "Projects",
        "href": "#projects"
      },
      {
        "name": "Articles",
        "href": "#articles"
      },
      {
        "name": "Resume",
        "href": "#resume"
      },
      {
        "name": "Contact",
        "href": "#contact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The parent component:

```
// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems';

// Import data
import data from '../../data/data.json';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
        <NavigationItems {...data.navbar.navItems} />
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

---

Doing something like:

```
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => (
  <>
  props.map((item, index) => {
    return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
  })
  </>
);
```

Results in:

```
ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx
  Line 5:27:  Parsing error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?

webpack 5.65.0 compiled with 2 errors in 131 ms
ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:5:28
TS1382: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?
    3 | const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => (
    4 |   <>
  > 5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
      |                            ^
    6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
    7 |   })
    8 |   </>

ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:6:5
TS1109: Expression expected.
    4 |   <>
    5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
  > 6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
      |     ^^^^^^
    7 |   })
    8 |   </>
    9 | );

ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:6:21
TS2304: Cannot find name 'item'.
    4 |   <>
    5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
  > 6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
      |                     ^^^^
    7 |   })
    8 |   </>
    9 | );

ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:6:37
TS2304: Cannot find name 'index'.
    4 |   <>
    5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
  > 6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
      |                                     ^^^^^
    7 |   })
    8 |   </>
    9 | );

ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:6:45
TS2304: Cannot find name 'item'.
    4 |   <>
    5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
  > 6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
      |                                             ^^^^
    7 |   })
    8 |   </>
    9 | );

ERROR in src/components/navigation/NavigationItems.tsx:7:3
TS1381: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?
     5 |   props.map((item, index) => {
     6 |     return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
  >  7 |   })
       |   ^
     8 |   </>
     9 | );
    10 |
```

---

This is what the `props` object looks like that is being passed in from `<NavigationItems {...data.navbar.navItems}`:

```
{0: {name: "Bio", href: "#bio"}, 1: {name: "Projects", href: "#projects"}, 2: {name: "Articles", href: "#articles"}, 3: {name: "Resume", href: "#resume"}, 4: {name: "Contact", href: "#contact"}}
```

Comment: props is an object,not an array. You'd have to do something like `Object.entries(props).map(([key, value]) => ... )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with the help of Derek's comment and [Matt U's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70705644/3123109).

It not only needed to be in a `React.Fragment` `(<></>)`, but inside of curly braces `{}`.

The parent component:

```
// Navigation.tsx

// Bootstrap imports
import { Container, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';

// Component imports
import NavigationItems from './NavigationItems';

// Import data
import data from '../../data/data.json';

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar>
      <Container>
        <Navbar.Brand>{data.navbar.navBrand}</Navbar.Brand>
        <NavigationItems {...data.navbar.navItems} />
      </Container>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

The child component:

```
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => (
  <>
    { 
      Object.entries(props).map((item, index) => {
        return <a href={item[1].href} key={index}>{item[1].name}</a>
      })
    }
  </>
);

export default NavigationItems;
```

This is the original data format:

```
{
  "navbar": {
    "navBrand": "My Name",
    "navItems": [
      {
        "name": "Bio",
        "href": "#bio"
      },
      {
        "name": "Projects",
        "href": "#projects"
      },
      {
        "name": "Articles",
        "href": "#articles"
      },
      {
        "name": "Resume",
        "href": "#resume"
      },
      {
        "name": "Contact",
        "href": "#contact"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But what is actually being passed in to the `props` with `<NavigationItems {...data.navbar.navItems} />` is:

```
{0: {name: "Bio", href: "#bio"}, 1: {name: "Projects", href: "#projects"}, 2: {name: "Articles", href: "#articles"}, 3: {name: "Resume", href: "#resume"}, 4: {name: "Contact", href: "#contact"}}
```

So needed to use `Object.entries(props).map()`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example isn't returning anything. When you enclose the body of an arrow function in curly braces e.g. `const myFunc = () => { ...body }` you have to explicitly put a `return` inside. What you want is to omit the curly braces.

However, that will still not work, because you'll be returning an array rather than an element. You can use a React fragment, such as:

```jsx
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => (
  <>
  props.map((item, index) => {
    return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
  })
  </>
);
```

I typed this on my phone so I hope that syntax is correct. But the `<>` indicates a fragment. You can read more here: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Note that `<>...</>` is shorthand for `<React.Fragment>...</React.Fragment>`

Comment: Thanks, but still running into issues when trying to use fragments. I've appended my updated code and the new error messages to the bottom of my question.

Comment: You forgot to put `{` and `}` around the JS expression in the middle of the JSX.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should return the map result.

```
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => {
    // add return here
    return props.map((item, index) => {
        return <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>
    })
};

export default NavigationItems;
```

or to simplify (maybe), you can write it like this

```
const NavigationItems = (props: {name: string, href: string}[]): JSX.Element => 
    props.map((item, index) => <a href={item.href} key={index}>{item.name}</a>)
```

Comment: This still won't work because a component can't return an array for the render.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. Thanks for pointing it out!